# RelativeLayout doesn't obey parent size (with layout_weight)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

I haven't been able to find a similar problem to the one I'm having on StackOverflow - basically, I have a simple XML layout with a vertical LinerLayout which uses layout_weight to make a 10/50/40 split, which is what I want (as seen below):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".1"        
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"      
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/green">   

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/preview_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/level_preview_back"
        android:focusable="false" />

</LinearLayout>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".4"        
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

BUT - I want the HorizontalScrollView and the ImageView to be overlayed (i.e. take up the exact same space on on top of the other), so I insert a RelativeLayout as such:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".1"        
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"      
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/green">   

        <RelativeLayout                 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"         
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/preview_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/level_preview_back"
        android:focusable="false" />

   </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".4"        
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I do this, the layout_weight (10/50/40 split) breaks and suddently the LinearLayout that now contains the RelativeLayout takes up virtually all the screen in the previews.

Anyone experienced this problem or know a good workaround?  I've also tried replacing the LinearLayout with the RelativeLayout directly and I have the same problem.

**EDIT:** Looking further into this issue, there seems to be more to it.  As I commented below, I was able to get around the problem by wrapping LinearLayouts around the TextViews, though I'm not sure why that worked.  Updating my SDK and plugin didn't help (though I did need to do it....)

Moving further along with my task, I hit a second problem - I was implementing a second version of the overlapped ScrollView & ImageView (which were done with a FrameLayout as suggested by Karsten) but the layout_weight problems began anew.

Testing various arrangements, it seems that the issue is very much related to the image I'm using, which is quite large in resolution.  Replacing them with a smaller image corrects the issues - it looks like using large images in either ImageViews or as backgrounds to LinearLayouts tends to ruin the layouts for the entire screen.

**EDIT #2:** I've actually loaded the XML on to two different devices and it renders exactly as it should....  This seems to be a bug with the Eclipse XML layout viewer?

(Please excuse the poor XML formatting - the Eclipse Android xml editor is frustrating in that regard...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML you've posted works fine for me in the Eclipse preview. Are you running the latest version of the Android plugin?

Note that you can replace the middle LinearLayout and RelativeLayout with a single FrameLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:text="string/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="#00ff00" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/preview_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:focusable="false" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:text="string/title2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hm..  Thanks for the reply.  I actually came back here to post my own answer - looks like if I wrap the TextViews in their own LinearLayouts and apply the layout_weight to the LinearLayouts instead of directly to the TextViews, then it displays correctly.  I'll also check to make sure my Eclipse is up to date.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip on FrameLayout - you're right, they seem to be better for the sorts of things I'm trying to achieve.